# Keep track of total amount of instances created for class and subclass

Tags: c#

Note: This is a homework assignment.

I have two classes, one inherits from the other. The assignment tells us to make the classes able to keep track of the total amount of instances created of each class.

```
class FirstClass 
{
  private static int _instancesCreated = 0;
  public FirstClass()
  {
    _instancesCreated++;
  }
}
```

That piece of code works well as far as I know. The problem is that I have a subclass which has to call the constructor of it's parent class.

```
class SecondClass:FirstClass 
{
  public SecondClass() : base()
  {
  }
}
```

So now the problem becomes how to properly separate the two. Since I have to call the parent constructor the _instancesCreated for that class will become incorrect, although I suppose it's true in a sense...?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Add another static private field in the derived class and increment that as you do the parent. Obviously derived instances will be counted as parent instances, maybe that's what you want, or maybe that's what the problem is.

Comment: If you want to treat `FirstClass` seperate, then have your program calculate `FirstClass.instances - SecondClass.instances`. That gives you the total instances of only `FirstClass`

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett The subtraction way will not suffice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Unfortunately the assignment is not specifying that. I'm not sure what the teacher wants to I'm thinking either way will do.

Comment: @eml Ive edited my answer - for seperate counts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to make _instancesCreated protected, and then decrement it in each of your subclasses constructors. That's how you make _instancesCreated store only the number of base class instances. For counting subclasses instances you should add static fields for each of them, and increment them in constructors, just like you did in your base class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SecondClass:FirstClass 
{ 
  private static int _sub_instancesCreated = 0;
  public SecondClass() : base()
  {
      _sub_instancesCreated ++;
  }
}
```

---

### separately

```
class FirstClass 
{
  private static int _instancesCreated = 0;
  public FirstClass()
  {
    _instancesCreated++;
  }

protected FirstClass(int i)
  {

  }
}

 class SecondClass:FirstClass 
    { 
      private static int _sub_instancesCreated = 0;
      public SecondClass() : base(2) //dummy
      {
          _sub_instancesCreated ++;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It will work to count subclasses. But _instancesCreated will store a wrong number of base class instances.

Comment: @DmitryKruglov when you crete a sub class  - the base also created !!

Comment: @RoyiNamir (referring to your comment) Yes that is correct, in theory the base class is also created. I *think* that's not what the teacher is looking for though.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Your are right, but eml wants to count them separately.

Comment: @eml in theory ?? in Reality !

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it will do for now, supposed that only argumentless constructor will be used to instantiate FirstClass.

Comment: @DmitryKruglov Also a protected constructor of the father can be helpful

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yeah, in this case a protected consturctor makes perfect sense. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution (if a bit overkill):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new BaseClass();
            new BaseClass();
            new DerivedClass();

            Console.WriteLine("Base classes: {0}, Derived classes: {1}",
                              BaseClass.CountInstances<BaseClass>(),
                              BaseClass.CountInstances<DerivedClass>());
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public static Dictionary<Type, int> InstanceCount =
            new Dictionary<Type, int>();

        public static int CountInstances<T>() where T : BaseClass
        {
            return BaseClass.InstanceCount.ContainsKey(typeof(T)) ? BaseClass.InstanceCount[typeof(T)] : 0;
        }

        public BaseClass()
        {
            if (!InstanceCount.ContainsKey(this.GetType()))
            {
                InstanceCount[this.GetType()] = 0;
            }

            InstanceCount[this.GetType()]++;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public DerivedClass()
            : base()
        {

        }
    }
}
```